# Haml partial with Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, haml

I am referencing a HAML partial within Sinatra:

```
= haml :'_review', :locals => {:someLocal => someLocal}
```

Seems like I am doing this wrong as I am including the underscore in the partial name.  Isn't there a way w/ Sinatra to say its a partial and leave off the underscore.

Without Sinatra I think its something like this:

```
= render :partial => 'review', :locals => {:someLocal => someLocal}
```

however cannot get that to work with sinatra.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything "wrong", when calling a view you use the file's basename, if it has an underscore you use an underscore; if not, you don't. I don't really see much benefit in using underscores or in leaving off the underscore. That said, I'm the maintainer of [Sinatra Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial), and since some other people wanted [it it's in there](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial#configuration-options).

```
enable :partial_underscores

partial :review # will look for the _review.haml file.
```

If you wish to turn it off for a particular call:

```
# will render the non_underscored_partial.haml file.
partial :non_underscored_partial, :underscores => false
```

Answer (score 1):

In sinatra all views are rendered with views/layout.erb - if it's present - and you have to have a `yield` call in it.

If you have a nested layout, then you have to build the layout structure in the "controller" side, as it is described in [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Templates%20with%20%3Ccode%3Eyield%3C/code%3E%20and%20nested%20layouts).

Comment: @forumuser as is made clear [in the instructions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Views%20/%20Templates), Sinatra is language agnostic, so if a template language is supported then its call to the template will be the same e.g. `erb :index` calls `index.erb`. `haml :index` calls `index.haml`. `yield` in a layout will yield whichever template was called with the `layout.EXT` where "EXT" is the language extension (unless something else is passed as an option).